# What is the mean smallest Hamming distance asymptotic to?

Tags: probability, limits, asymptotics

Consider a collection $S_n$ of $n$ independent and uniformly distributed  binary strings, each of length $n$.   Let $f(S_n)$ be the smallest [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between any pair of strings in $S_n$.  I am interested in $\mathbb{E}(f(S_n))$.

Let $X$ be the Hamming distance between a randomly chosen pair of strings in $S_n$. If we let $\mu = \frac{n}{2}$ then we know by the [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) that:

$$P( X \le (1-\delta)\mu) \le e^{-\frac{\delta^2\mu}{2}}, \qquad 0 \le \delta \le 1.$$

and

$$Pr( X \ge (1+\delta)\mu)\le e^{-\frac{\delta^2\mu}{2+\delta}}, \qquad 0 \le \delta$$

Therefore we may suspect that $\mathbb{E}(f(S_n))$ will be close to $\frac{n}{2}$ for large $n$.

For small $n$, we have e.g. $\mathbb{E}(f(S_4)) = \frac{3}{4}$.

My question is this:

> What is $\mathbb{E}(f(S_n))$ asymptotic to?

I am particularly interested in the lower order terms.

Comment: It seems to me your first inequality (with a bit extra work) already implies $E[f(S_n)] \to n/2 + o(n)$, i.e. the coefficient in the linear term is $\frac12$.  So are you asking about the sub-linear terms in $o(n)$?

Comment: @antkam. Yes that’s what I am interested in.

Comment: @felipa Is the answer below sufficient, or do you want a proof?

Comment: @mathworker21 I was hoping for a proof, at least for the general form. I don’t mind if the constant is derived by fitting.

Comment: Yes I was hoping for a proof @mathworker21.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody more qualified than me has attempted a solution.  Here's my attempt.  It is non-rigorous in a few places and I will point them out.

As the OP implies, the linear term of $E[f(S_n)]$ is $\frac n2$.  The min distance is obviously going to be less than $\frac n2$, so there is a gap $g(n)$, i.e. $E[f(S_n)] = \frac n2 - g(n)$ where $g(n)$ is positive and sub-linear.

> Claim: for any constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the gap $g(n) > c\sqrt{n}$ asymptotically.
>   (Note that this is weaker than Empy2's experimental finding of $g(n) \approx c \sqrt{n \ln n}.)$

My approach is to find $h(n)$ s.t. $P(f(S_n) > \frac n2 - h(n)) \to 0$.  This would imply $E[f(S_n)] \le \frac n2 - h(n)$ and provide a lower bound to the gap: $g(n) = \frac n2 - E[f(S_n)] \ge h(n)$.

Let $D_{ij}$ denote the distance between string $i$ and string $j$, for $1 \le i < j \le n$.  Note that all $D_{ij}$ are identically distributed as $D\sim Binomial(n, \frac12)$, although they are not independent.  We have:

$$
\begin{array}{}
P(f(S_n) > \frac n2 - h(n)) &=& P(\bigcap_{i<j} ~(D_{ij} > \frac n2 - h(n)))\\
&\overset{?}{<}& \prod_{i < j}~ P(D_{ij} > \frac n2 - h(n)) \\
&=& P(D > \frac n2 - h(n))^{n(n-1)/2} \\
&:=& a
\end{array}
$$

The "$\overset{?}{<}$" step is biggest non-rigorous hole in my approach.  The intuition is that having some $D_{ij} > \frac n2 - h(n)$ would "space out" strings $i$ and $j$, and make it harder for another $D_{i'j'} > \frac n2 - h(n)$, i.e. the two events are "anti-correlated", so the probability of the conjunction is less than if they were independent events, i.e. the product of individual probabilities.

Anyway, the next non-rigorous step is to use the Gaussian approximation to Binomial.  We have $Var(D) = \frac n4$ so $\frac Dn \sim N(\frac 12, \sigma= {1 \over 2\sqrt{n}})$.

$$
\begin{array}{}
b := P(D > \frac n2 - h(n)) &=& P(\frac Dn - \frac 12 > -{h(n) \over n})\\
&=& 1 - P(\frac Dn - \frac 12 \le -{h(n)\over n})\\
&\approx& 1 - \Phi(-{h(n) / n \over \sigma})\\
&=& 1 - \Phi(-{2 h(n) \over \sqrt{n}})\\
&:=& 1 - r(n)
\end{array}
$$

where $\Phi(x) = P(N(0,1) \le x)$ is the cdf of a standard normal variable.

Note that $-{2 h(n) \over \sqrt{n}} < 0 \implies r(n) := \Phi(-{2 h(n) \over \sqrt{n}}) \in (0, \frac12) \implies b \in (\frac12, 1)$, and in fact for interesting choices of $h(n)$ we will have $r(n) \to 0, b \to 1$.  However, all we need is that $a = b^{n(n-1)/2} \to 0$, and this can be achieved by having $r(n) \to 0, b \to 1$ slowly enough.  But first, we can now prove:

> Claim: for any constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the gap $g(n) > c\sqrt{n}$ asymptotically.

Proof: take $h(n) = c\sqrt{n} \implies b = 1 - \Phi(-2c) = $ some constant $< 1 \implies a = b^{n(n-1)/2} \to 0. ~\square$

**Further thoughts:**  When $h(n) = c\sqrt{n}$, we have $r(n) = \Phi(-2c)=$ a constant $> 0$.  More interestingly, we can increase $h(n)$ beyond $\sqrt{n}$ and let $r(n) \to 0$.  One way to do that and still have $a \to 0$ is to have $t(n) := {1 \over r(n)}$ grow slower than $n^2$, i.e. in the little-o notation:

$$t(n) := {1 \over r(n)} = o(n^2)$$

because if the above holds, then $n^2 / t(n) \to \infty$ and:

$$a = (1 - r(n))^{n(n-1)/2} = \big( (1-{1 \over t(n)})^{t(n)} \big)^{n(n-1)/2t(n)} \to e^{-n(n-1)/2t(n)} \to 0$$

At this point, the problem becomes bounding the tail of a Gaussian $r(n) = \Phi(-{2h(n) \over \sqrt{n}})$. I'm sure lots of work has been done on this issue, and I am completely out of my depth.

One weird aspect is that in this approach, we need to *lower* bound the Gaussian tail: we need $r(n) \to 0$ slowly enough s.t. $a \to 0$.  So e.g. Chebyshev's inequality which gives the upperbound

$$r(n) = \Phi(-{2h(n) \over \sqrt{n}}) \le \frac12 {n \over (2 h(n))^2}$$

is in the wrong direction and does not help (at least not in this direct way).

Comment: @mathworker21 - if you have time, I'd love to hear your comments re: my answer above.  It seems like the kind of thing which you can improve considerably over what I did.

Comment: @leonbloy - Sorry to drag you in, but this question immediately made me think of you, since you know so much about coding.  Would love to hear your thoughts (if you have time) on both the OP question and my answer approach.  Thanks!

Comment: tagging someone only works when they have already commented. I didn't get a notification for your tag. I just happened to run into it now (so maybe it does work :) ). But nice answer! I'll look at it later today.

Comment: for the note in your first claim, I think you want to say weaker than $\Omega(\sqrt{n\log n})$. Saying $ > c\sqrt{n}$ is not weaker than $O(\sqrt{n\log n})$; it is orthogonal.

Comment: should your argument give $\Omega(\sqrt{n\log n})$ or no? I am currently thinking about the anti-correlation "hole". I agree with your intuition for it.

Comment: also, I'd appreciate if you looked at my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513485/testing-whether-polynomial-is-in-algebra-of-given-collection-of-polynomials

Comment: Thank you for this. I am still hoping we can pin down the last details.

Answer (score 1):

Between 2 and 100, a fair estimate seems to be 
$$\mathbb{E}(f(S_n))\approx \frac n2+1-\frac12\sqrt{\pi n\ln(n+1)}$$
Here is the graph after $n/2$ has been subtracted from both sides
[image]

It may be possible to derive that formula or a similar one by assuming all of the $n\choose2$ distances are independent and normally distributed.

Comment: How do we know the function has this exact form asymptotically?  In particular, how do you know the $\sqrt{n \ln(n+1)}$ term is right?

Comment: Mostly I don't, I experimentally fitted to my data, which was 1000 trials for each $n$.  Note the cdf of the maximum is the $n$th power of the cdf of the original function, and the minimum is similar.  Then assume the original is normally distributed.

Comment: Note my graph is two graphs - formula and simulated data - but you can only tell them apart for $n\lt 10$